# Change the data in cassandra using update command?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a way to update Cassandra database to update the table like in MySQL?
  I have data stored in cassandra and I need to update the data. Is there any update command to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can perform an `UPDATE` (from the CQL shell) to a row in the database.  However, unlike MySQL you can only specify the primary key(s) in the `WHERE` clause.  This example assumes a table called "products" with a primary key of "productNumber."

```
UPDATE products
SET description1='PROD DESC1'
WHERE productNumber='ITEM00123';
```

If a row does not exist for the primary key you have specified, a new one will be created.

For more information, see the DataStax documentation on the `UPDATE` CQL command that abhi linked in his answer.

Edit: I'm not sure about pure Javascript, but there is a Cassandra driver ([node-cassandra-client](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client)) for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).  You can use that driver to connect to Cassandra and peform an update in Javascript.  Here's an example of how to perform the above `UPDATE`:

```
 var conOptions = { hosts: ['127.0.0.1:19170'],
                    keyspace: 'productKeyspace',
                    use_bigints: false };
 var con = new PooledConnection(conOptions);
 var cql = 'UPDATE products SET description1=? where productNumber=?';
 var params = ['PROD DESC1', 'ITEM00123'];
 con.execute(cql, params, function(err) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
   con.shutdown(callback);
 });
```

For more information, check out [Rackspace's doc on the node.js driver](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/rackspace-contributes-cassandra-cql-driver-for-node-js/).

Comment: Thank u sir. Can I do the same from a javascript?